# Map only specific properties from a model to table fields. Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm running out of ideas how to implement the thing in a simple way.

Assuming we have class which also serves as a model of a database table, but the case is that I require to map only the few properties to be fields in the table.

The annotation (using [NotMapped] annotation on a model class properties) approach is not a good one for me, we are following the Fluent API way...

I know I can Ignore(p => p.SomeProperty) but it is still a wrong solution because I have a lot of properties to ignore.

I've been thinking of some kind of templates using abstract classes or interfaces containing the properties I require for each class->table relation, and processing them by reflection passing the template and retrieving EntityTypeConfiguration but it seems for me a very messy solution.

Thank you,
and May the force be with you :)

Comment: Maybe you should rethink the idea of having a single model-class then. Having 2 separate pojos will give you some overhead code, but will also give you more flexibility + you won't need workarounds to let the model do what you want.

Comment: I think the best option is to have separate classes for models and DB mapping. You can use AutoMapper https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/4.1.1 to automatically map model properties to the entity class.

Comment: @jHilscher, As I understand you propose to use an additional layer between existing classes and the EF (as example Company.cs -> CompanyModel.cs -> CompanyModelMapp)? This was the initial approach, but after discussing it with my team we decided to use existing classes as models avoiding duplicating code (Company.cs-> CompanyMap.cs)

Comment: @AlexanderMP could you please provide me a small abstract example? suppose we have a class called Company which is used across multiple packages in the solution. What I want is Company to be a model for the table.

Comment: I, and everyone I've seen so far, usually created a separate namespace, or even project, for everything DB related, where all the entities reside. For the rest, that's the model, create a separate class somewhere. Once per application domain configure the automapper, and use it when you need to map from the entity to the model. https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki

Comment: If you don't get an answer before that, I'll illustrate an alternative that will work both ways without any configuration.

Comment: Agree with previous comments. But would use aggregation:
https://gist.github.com/segor/7a39924569eaa8d37455

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> I know I can Ignore(p => p.SomeProperty) but it is still a wrong solution because I have a lot of properties to ignore.

Maybe first of all ask yourself why do you have so many properties, maybe your entity should be spitted into several entities? It seems more like you have to solve an architectural issue rather than a technical one.

I'd consider one of the following approaches:

- You could have several entities mapped to the same table, but each entity containing just properties that are required in a specific use case. (focus on *Single responsibility* principle)
- I don't know the exact structure of your DB model, but it could be the case that you can use *Table per Hierarchy* pattern.
- If none of above is still a solution, consider at least grouping these properties into *complex types*.

Comment: Forgot to mention, you could also figure this out with _EF conventions_. But still, this looks like a workaround to a badly designed domain model.